# Coping dictionary within a dictionary(Nested dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a dictionary like as `dict1  = { 0 : 0, 1 : 1, 2 : { 0: 0, 1 : 1}}` (which is also having a dictionary as value). I want to keep store these value same for some modification checking purpose. So now I am copy this dictionary content into another dictionary as `dict2 = dict1.copy()`. Now I am changing the values of `dict2` like as `{ 0 : -1, 1 : -2, 2: { 0 : -1, i : -2}}`. Now the problem is that my `dict1`'s dictionary value also changing as `{ 0 : 0, 1 : 1, 2:{ 0 : -1, 1 : -2}}`. Here you can see this easily `dict1`'s key 2 values also changing as dict2's key 2 values.

How should I copy the `dict2` from `dict1` so if change `dict2`'s key 2 value this should not put a impact on the `dict1`'s key = 2 values?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. What version are you using and how are you changing the values in dict 2?

Comment: @J.T. `d={1:{2:3}};e=d.copy();e[1][2]=4;d`

Comment: @KennyTM Thank you. That example coupled with "d[1] is e[1]" helped me understand exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) to perform a deep copy.